# Where do java packages live on a linux system? Package org.json does not exist Error using javac

Tags: java, javac, org.json

I am trying to compile a library I wrote, using javac and I am getting the error: `package org.json does not exist`.  My program includes `org.json.JSONArray` and `org.json.JSONException`.

I have this package installed on my computer because I have successfully compiled android apps that import `org.json` libraries.  I'm pretty sure all I have to do is specify a `-classpath` but I have been unable to find where these files live on my system (ubuntu 10.10 64-bit sun-java6).

Having been unable to find these on my own system I downloaded the `org.json` files from [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java), but I was unable to compile them individually because they were co-dependent on each other.

So I have a couple questions:

1. Does anyone know where the org.json
   package lives from android sdk
   install?
2. Where might I find a tutorial
   explaining these basic concepts
   regarding compiling, and javac.

Comment: I *always* install everything Java-related on Un*x systems in the user's directory and I do this without needing root privileges (you cannot do it on Windows: on Windows you **must** have admin right to install Java).  So, for me, *"java packages live somewhere in the user's directory"* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever you like.  What you need to do is examine your CLASSPATH variable, and make sure it includes the directory with your library.

Here's the first thing:

```
  $ echo $CLASSPATH
```

and you'll see your classpath as it is.

Now you need to find the jar file containing the org.json; consult the documentation, but it may be something as simple as `json.jar`.  On most LINUX systems you can then just run

```
 $ locate json.jar
```

And you'll get a path name for the jarfile.  Make sure that path is part of your CLASSPATH and you'll be in fat city.

Oh, and the "[Getting started](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html)" tutorials at <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle are the easiest place to start.

---

Actually, having looked at the files, they may not be packaged as a jar file.  In that case, you want to put them into your sources starting at some top directory (`src` in this example.)

```
   /src
       /org/json/ ... put the json files here
       ... put your files here
```

and when you compile, they'll all be included, which will resolve all the dependencies.

Again, the place to look for first steps is that tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever external jars you need to compile with should be on the classpath when you compile. The most non-invasive way to do this is do add these items to the javac command line such as

`javac -classpath /path/to/json.jar;. -g YourClass.java`

or more likely if you use an IDE, add these jars to your referenced jars of the project in your IDE.

It usually isn't a good idea to pollute the global `$CLASSPATH` variable, as this then gets pulled in for everything you do with java, which may cause unintended conflicts.

Comment: I tried following your instructions and I got that `-g` was an invalid option.

Answer (score -1):

use "java" command instead of "javac"